# RSOP resolves wrong computer name

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy

I have imaged a computer using Acronis Snap Deploy.

The source computer from where the image have been taken is **SOURCEW7**, and the computer created with this image is **W7TEST**

When I do a RSOP (Resultant Set of Policies) of **W7TEST**, the report says that the computer name is **SOURCEW7**, and the domain of the computer is **Local**. Though, the domain isnt called "Local", it's another domain name. And of course the GPOs doesnt applies.

The source computer (SOURCEW7) was in a workgroup at the moment of taking the image of it. I have added W7TEST on the domain after the image has been pushed into it.

I dont understand why the RSOP says the computer name is SOURCEW7, because there is no entries in the DNS for SOURCEW7, and in Windows, the computer name is shown as "W7TEST" and is on the domain.

I have an error also in the RSOP saying "GP core failed".

How can I troubleshoot this issue? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Picture representing the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI2yd.png

Comment: Have you rebooted/restarted `W7TEST` after joining the domain?

Comment: Of course! Iv rebooted it a couple of times. Also, the SID of W7TEST have been changed by snap deploy so it wont be the same as SOURCEW7.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this forum post while browsing for answers on the same issue - in my case the computers generated from a VDI master showed the computer name of the master rather than the clone in RSOP.  I came across the following discussion that seems to indicate the credentials had become cached under the local system account, preventing computer group policy processing:
http://www.networksteve.com/forum/topic.php/Group_Policy_Access_Denied_for_computer_policy_only/?TopicId=39534&Posts=2

To remove the rogue cached credentials:

1. Use SysInternals PsExec to open a command prompt under the Local System account [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553]:
   From an Administrator command prompt: PsExec.exe -i -s cmd.exe
2. Open the Stored User Names and Passwords app under the Local System account:
   From the System account command prompt: rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
3. You should now see the credentials that are cached under the Local System account. Review the list for rogue suspects, and remove them. For me, this was straightforward. There were two credentials listed: one rogue cred (from my old WHS2011 config I suspect), and a second called virtualapp/didlogical. When I reviewed the credentials on machines that were working, they only had the virtualapp/didlogical credential listed.

This seems to have worked for me in the VDI environment.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a problem you are having with just the one machine, I would unjoin it from the domain and rejoin it.  Do you have multiple DCs?  It sounds like your domain infrastructure might be having some issues if the unjoin & join did not work.

Comment: Im having this issue with every computers that I have imaged with acronis snap deploy. I have 2 DCs. I did the RSOP from the PDC.

Comment: Did you sysprep the PC first?  Could it be grabbing the old GUID?

Comment: I have not syspreped it. The source computer (the one used to create the image) was not on the domain, so i dont think its about the GUID?

Comment: I am not familiar with acronis, but usually you have to have some way to strip out the GUID & related info.  You can still sysprep them using sysprep -oob, I think, but if you have a ton of them, you might want to sysprep the 'golden machine' and reimage depending on how acronis handles changing the GUID and how easy it is to mass image.

Comment: Acronis regenerates a new SID for each deployment. It this enough? Where does the RSOP can pull back the name of the "golden machine" when polling an imaged computer?

Comment: For your first question, no.  Refer here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961625.aspx.   I am not sure about the second question.

Answer (score 0):

'GP Core Failed' means that the Group Policies have not been applied. Normally, this means they have not be applied because of a communication failure.

Communication failure could be caused by time syncronisation failure, long network card startup time, encryption or authentication failure or some other reason.

As well as a communication failure from the Server to the Client, you also have a communication failure from the Client to the Server: the group policy service on the server is supposed to talk to the client to find out what domain the client is in, so that it can send the correct group policies.

Mostly this is easy to fix: the only problem is working out which easy problem is the cause. Check the logs on both server and client to see if it tells you why the group policy is not being applied correctly. Try this link: [Fixing Group Policy by using log files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775423%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)